# OrientDB & .Net driver: Unable to read data from the transport connection

Tags: orientdb

Getting error while reading network stream from a successful socket connection. PL see the debug log from orient DB:

```
2016-04-08 18:08:51:590 WARNI Not enough physical memory available for DISKCACHE: 1,977MB (heap=494MB). Set lower Maximum Heap (-Xmx setting on JVM) and restart OrientDB. Now
running with DISKCACHE=256MB [orientechnologies]
2016-04-08 18:08:51:606 INFO  OrientDB config DISKCACHE=-566MB (heap=494MB os=1,977MB disk=16,656MB) [orientechnologies]
2016-04-08 18:08:51:809 INFO  Loading configuration from: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/orientdb-2.1.5/config/orientdb-server-config.xml... [OServerConfigurationLoaderXml]
2016-04-08 18:08:52:292 INFO  OrientDB Server v2.1.5 (build 2.1.x@r${buildNumber}; 2015-10-29 16:54:25+0000) is starting up... [OServer]
2016-04-08 18:08:52:370 INFO  Databases directory: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\orientdb-2.1.5\databases [OServer]
2016-04-08 18:08:52:495 INFO  Listening binary connections on 127.0.0.1:2424 (protocol v.32, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener]
2016-04-08 18:08:52:511 INFO  Listening http connections on 127.0.0.1:2480 (protocol v.10, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener]
2016-04-08 18:08:52:573 INFO  Installing dynamic plugin 'studio-2.1.zip'... [OServerPluginManager]
2016-04-08 18:08:52:838 INFO  Installing GREMLIN language v.2.6.0 - graph.pool.max=50 [OGraphServerHandler]
2016-04-08 18:08:52:838 INFO  [OVariableParser.resolveVariables] Error on resolving property: distributed [orientechnologies]
2016-04-08 18:08:52:854 INFO  Installing Script interpreter. WARN: authenticated clients can execute any kind of code into the server by using the following allowed languages:
 [sql] [OServerSideScriptInterpreter]
2016-04-08 18:08:52:854 INFO  OrientDB Server v2.1.5 (build 2.1.x@r${buildNumber}; 2015-10-29 16:54:25+0000) is active. [OServer]
2016-04-08 18:08:57:986 INFO  /127.0.0.1:49243 - Connected [OChannelBinaryServer]
2016-04-08 18:08:58:002 INFO  /127.0.0.1:49243 - Writing short (2 bytes): 32 [OChannelBinaryServer]
2016-04-08 18:08:58:002 INFO  /127.0.0.1:49243 - Flush [OChannelBinaryServer]
2016-04-08 18:08:58:002 INFO  /127.0.0.1:49243 - Reading byte (1 byte)... [OChannelBinaryServer]
```

Using OrientDB .Net binary (C# driver) in Windows Vista. This was working fine until recently. Not sure what broke it...

Resetting TCP/IP using NetShell utility did not help.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the AVG anti-virus program that is blocking the socket. Added an exception in the program for localhost to fix the problem.